# MMQGIS Geocoder Request Denied Error - Using Google API Key

Tags: geocoding, api, google, mmqgis

I need to geocode 12,000 addresses, so I enabled billing and set up credentials to use the Google Geocoding API.  When I try to run the MMQGIS geocoder using my new API Key, I immediately get the message: Request Denied - 0 addresses geocoded.  I have enabled the Google Maps Geocoding API as well as the Google Maps Javascript API.

What else do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: I don't find the file... where is mmqgis_library.py?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out and posting for those who encounter the same issue.  I got the full error from Google:

REQUEST_DENIED Requests to this API must be over SSL. Load the API with "https://" instead of "http://".

To fix, change the URL in line 288 of  mmqgis_library.py to begin with https.